# Creating products using impex script?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice, impex

Am  new to Hybris product level.
Could you please advise me how to create new/add products into it using impex script.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can check existing sample impex files which are already exist in hybris installation. For example you can check electronic store impex files in `hybris/bin/ext-data/electronicsstore/resources/electronicsstore/import` folder.

Comment: Can I know why i have this errors ,,,,error finding existing item : column='catalogversion' value='', | column 8: cannot resolve value 'null' for attribute 'catalogversion'| column 8: cannot resolve value '' for attribute 'catalogversion';23191;1288, brand_5;Sony;ACC-CSPW;pieces;;;

Comment: You need to use existing catalog version, please check in your backoffice. Or. you can also import catalog impexes.

Comment: Can you help me to import this path C:\%path%\hybris\bin\custom\yb2bacceleratorstorefront\web\webroot\_ui\responsive\common\images\img_KE_PLP to Media script. I put something like that $commonResourcePath/images/img_KE_PLP/GK061S.png. But how to call the macro $commonResourcePath? thnks.